# How to identify iPhone/iPad user's itunes account information?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, synchronization, uniqueidentifier

I am working on a sync solution for my app, and I would like to be able to find out if the user who has just downloaded my app would like to sync the app's data with the same app but hosted on another device (e.g., installed on both an iPhone and an iPad), so I can prompt the user to set up syncing. Is there a way to either (a) get the user's iTunes account information (the email address or some other unique identifier), or (b) identify if the user's iTunes account has already installed the app on another device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres absolutely no way to get user's iTunes account information; that would be a security issue. The devices themselves have a Unique Device ID which can be obtained using:

> `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueidentifier];`

If you implement UrbanAirships AirMail /Push feature, if the user opts to receive push messages from your app, you can view how many users are opt'd in, and if you set the device name property, but thats about it.

Also, to sync data between multiple devices and such, I would suggest [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers).

Comment: Thanks - I sort of figured that this information wasn't available but I couldn't find anywhere that explicitly said that it wasn't. Thanks for the clarification.